# New Admob migration

Tags: android, admob

This is my first post in Stackoverflow.. I have been making use of Admob in most of my Android Apps.. I use GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-x.x.x.jar inside /libs folder in my application.. I have the following questions to migrate to the new Admob UI.

1. Is it mandatory to update my apps with the new adUnitId.. Is it ok to use the adUnitId of legacy Admob?
2. Is it necessary to migrate to Google Play Services from Android SDK before migrating to the new UI?
3. I see that legacy Admob will no longer be available from Aug 31st 2014. Does that mean that we have to update to the new adUnitId?
4. Will the earnings (after moving to the new Admob) be shown in the new Admob UI?
5. As there is no paypal payment, what will happen to my existing revenue?

Sorry for many questions.. I'm really puzzled with this UI migration.. I just want to make sure that the migration is smooth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, many different threads here:

1. Apps using the legacy AdUnitIds will continue to serve ads. But when you update your apps it would be a good idea to update the AdUnitId in them.
2. No. The UI and Google Play Services version of the library are orthogonal propositions.
3. No. But after that time you will no longer be able to update any apps using the non Play Services library.
4. Yes
5. Existing revenue (from old Admob UI) will be paid out.

Comment: William - Thanks a lot for answering all my questions.. 

Few clarifications pls-
1. After migrating to the new Admob UI, I assume that a new AdUnitId will be generated for each of the imported apps.. Hope my assumption is right.
2. Legacy Ads will not be served after Aug 31st 2014. Does that mean that apps with old AdUnitId will not get ads? (For the users who have not updated the app?)