# Upgrading to new AdMob - SDK upgrade required?

Tags: android, admob

Just a quick question concerning the [required upgrade to the new AdMob until August 31](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3309397?hl=en).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956048/should-we-prefer-admob-in-google-play-services-compared-to-old-admob-sdk) some people wrote, that the [old SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android) will become unsupported after the upgrade and that it is required to use [Google Play services SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play) then. Google Play services, however, are unsupported for Android versions below 2.3. My apps, again, support Android 2.1 and above and I would like to keep it like that for now. So I asked myself, if I really do need to upgrade to Google Play services, since I think I could not find any such information officially on Google's FAQs. I only read that one simply needs to replace some old publisher- and ad-IDs with new ones or something like that.

So is it necessary, to update to Google Play services yet?

Comment: You don't need to upgrade the publisher ids themselves, just the library code, instead of using the code from the old library you will use the code from the Google Play Services library. BUT i'm not sure what you should do with your 2.1 version, you might have to drop support.

Comment: Are you sure about that? In the FAQs I could not find anything about the necessity of upgrading to Google Play services SDK, just this: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/6025739?hl=en. But maybe I'll just do so anyway, I guess, I have really just few users using Android versions below 2.3. It's sad, however. / edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454767/new-admob-migration?rq=1 - Aw, here somebody says that one cannot upload new app versions using the old SDK. Okay.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you upgrade to Google Play Services version of Admob.

You don't need to drop support for your pre Gingerbread users (though they do account for less than 1% of users now), you just can't serve them ads.